# In Symfony, how do I authorise users using password/username once and subsequently use access/refresh token instead?

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, oauth-2.0

I've been trying to build a security layer for an application using Symfony. I have a web service that I can authorize users against using oAuth2 `Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant` - exchanging username/password for Bearer token looking like this:

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "access_token": "16fcd735-7063-42c2-83cd-448f2e9c4396",
  "refresh_token": "bc3d5d57-a5ef-445b-ac28-714c3bdfda46",
  "expires_in": 43197,
  "scope": "",
  "user_id": "",
  "username": ""
  "user_roles": {
      "ROLE_ADMIN": "ACTIVE"
  },
}
```

Once authorised, I can use access_token to access other API endpoints.

---

I have little experience dabbling with Symfony security so I have a problem wrapping my head around the implementation for this. I've found **New in Symfony 2.4: Customize the Security Features with ease**, **How to Authenticate Users with API Keys**, **How to Create a custom Authentication Provider** and everything seems rather straightforward, but for the life of mine I cannot understand how and at which moment I switch from `UsernamePasswordToken` to `MyCustomOauthToken`?

Do I setup a second firewall that allows through only users with UsernamePasswordToken, as per [Security Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#only-authenticating-for-certain-urls):

```
public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
{
    // set the only URL where we should look for auth information
    // and only return the token if we're at that URL
    $targetUrl = '/login/check';
    if (!$this->httpUtils->checkRequestPath($request, $targetUrl)) {
        return;
    }
[...]
```

Also, do I store API token data in the custom token, or as part of user entity?

Much obliged for any input on this.